# Flex : mobile application cannot work in android 4.3 or 4.4 (Unfortunately , (App_Name) has stopped )

Tags: android, apache-flex

I have finished for developing mobile application and it works fine in android version 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich ) but , it doesn't work in version 4.3 (Jelly Bean) or 4.4 (KitKat) make error message
(Unfortunately , (App_Name) has stopped ) and the application not start.

Tools Used :=

IDE => Falsh builder 4.6.

Sdk => Flex4.6.

Update : the application run when release a shared AIR and doesn't work when a captive runtime.

Please help .

Comment: Don't know if it's related, and I can't remember the details, but we had similar issues with iOS upgrades (got blank screens).  Moving to Apache Flex 4.11 (latest at the time) resolved that problem for us.  Might we worth a try...

Comment: Which version of AIR are you using with Flex 4.6?  Also, what do you see in LogCat when your app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Flex and Air are you using.  Android 4.4 requires at least Air 4.0.  Just to let you know that Google is going to stop using the shared Air runtime from the website.  So you will need to use a captive runtime.  The reason that it works with the shared Air is because when the application is downloaded it downloads the most recent version of Air from the Google Play store.

If you are only using the supplied Air version from I recommend downloading the downloader from Apache Flex.  You can then download the most current version of Air and the most current version of Flex Compiler.  This will be required to support the most recent versions of Android OS's

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Adobe AIR version installed on your mobile (check in Google Play Store). Updating to version 21.0.0.176 solved this problem in my case (HTC One Mini with Android 4.4) and Adobe Flash SDK 4.6

Thanks.